# Seeking Clarification on Proof for P(n, n) = P(n, n-1) Equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, factorial

I've encountered a mathematical challenge that has me scratching my head, and I'm hoping to get some assistance in validating my solution. The problem revolves around proving the equality of P(n, n) and P(n, n-1). I'm eager to confirm if my approach is on the right track. Here's the situation:

**Problem**: Demonstrate the equality P(n, n) = P(n, n-1) using the following two approaches:

**a) Simplification Approach**: My initial strategy was to simplify both sides of the equation and demonstrate their equality. Through some manipulation, I managed to express P(n, n) and P(n, n-1) in terms of factorials. I suspect they're equal, but I'm not entirely certain about my simplification process. I'd be incredibly grateful if someone could review my work and provide their insights.

**b) Multiplication Principle Approach**: Additionally, I've considered employing the multiplication principle to further solidify the equation's validity. I have a hunch that there's a connection between the two expressions waiting to be uncovered through this principle. However, I'm currently grappling with the precise steps needed to execute this approach. If anyone has any pointers, suggestions, or an outline for implementing the multiplication principle in this context, I'd truly appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Any lineup of $n$ people out of $n$ corresponds to a lineup of $n-1$ people out of $n$ with the final leftover person standing alone and left out in the doorway rather at the end of the line.

Comment: "*there's a connection waiting to be uncovered*"  You can multiply anything by $1$ and not change the value.

Comment: As a first step, perhaps that you could explain us the meaning of $P(n,n)$ and of $P(n,n-1)$.

Comment: $$P(n,n) = \frac{n!}{(n-n)!} = n \cdot (n-1) \cdots 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1
= n \cdot (n-1) \cdots 3 \cdot 2 = \frac{n!}{(n-(n-1))!} = P(n, n-1)$$